# How do I tell django-admin which settings module to use?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings, manage.py

When I run `django-admin` with `--settings` switch, it fails:

```
(env) $ django-admin help --settings=myapp.settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/srv/http/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'

(env) $ ls myapp/settings.py
myapp/settings.py
```

But `manage.py` works just fine. To make it clear, I'd like to have additional `settings.py` for development environment.

Also, importing settings from this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import myapp.settings
```

works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/) indeed says:

> `manage.py` does the same thing as `django-admin` but takes care of a few things for you:
>
> - It **puts your project’s package on `sys.path`.**
> - It sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable so that it points to your project’s `settings.py` file.

But it also says:

> If you need to switch between multiple Django settings files, use `django-admin` with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or the `--settings` command line option.

And all the examples are along the following lines:

```
$ django-admin migrate --settings=mysite.settings
```

The thing is for it to work [your project dir must be in `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523010/52499). And one way to achieve this is:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project django-admin help --settings=myapp.settings
```

Or you can use [--pythonpath](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption--pythonpath) switch, or set `PYTHONPATH` in advance.